# Can I persuade an automatically generated constructor to zero my POD class members?

Tags: c++

Let's say I've defined a class containing some simple POD members, and I was too lazy to write out a default constructor to init all the class members to default values. Instead, I asked the compiler to do that for me:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    int x;
    // etc.
}
```

I've tested with MSVC, and `x` is **not** initialized to zero by this auto-generated constructor: for a local object of class `Foo`, `x` was set to 0xcccccccc, which is the value I'd expect for an uninitialized stack variable.

My question is whether there is a standards-compliant way to convince the compiler to zero-init these POD members automatically. I say "standards compliant" because I need to be able to rely on other compilers to behave similarly. And I say "automatically" because I don't want to have to write out a constructor that lists every class member if I can avoid it.

Comment: How about `int x = 0;` ?

Comment: @Slava I hadn't thought of that. It still requires everything to have a default value specified, which isn't as simple as everything being zero, but it does mean I don't have to list the class members again, which was my main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are two solutions:

1. Either define a default initializer of the members as in the answer of lubgr which just showed up.
2. Or always prefer to value initialize your class instances where you could default initialize them: `Foo an_obj{};` in place of `Foo an_obj;`.

Comment: These are both worth considering in different situations. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use in-class member initializers like this:

```
class Foo {
    int x = 0;;
    int y{}; // same effect.
};
```

The advantage is consistency across constructors that are possibly added later on. This approach is also recommended by the [Core Guidelines C.45](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c45-dont-define-a-default-constructor-that-only-initializes-data-members-use-in-class-member-initializers-instead).

A disadvantage can arise when such a class is declared in a header file, because the type of all member variables that are initialized that way must be known and can't be forward-declared.

Comment: **All member variables** initialized or otherwise must be defined and not just declared.